# javascript date difference showing wrong in ios

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to add a timer using the function, but it's working fine in windows, but showing the wrong timer in IOS.

```
enddate = "2023-04-25 00:00:00"; 

getEventTimer() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if(this._diff > 0) {
        this._days = this.getDays(this._diff);
        this._hours = this.getHours(this._diff);
        this._minutes = this.getMinutes(this._diff);
        this._seconds = this.getSeconds(this._diff);
      } else {
        this._days = 0;
        this._hours = 0;
        this._minutes = 0;
        this._seconds = 0;
      }
      
      const s:any = new Date(this.enddate.toLocaleString().replace(/-/g, "/"));
      const t:any = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/-/g, "/"));
      this._diff = s - t;
    }, 1000);

  }

 getDays(t) {
    return Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }

  getHours(t) {
    return Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  }

  getMinutes(t) {
    return Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  }

  getSeconds(t) {
    return Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  }
```

..................................................................................................................................

expecting the correct timer.

Comment: not just ios, Safari handles `Date()` differently.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)